# ¿Cómo dejar seleccionado los botones durante un rellenado de formulario para enviar su valor?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

```js
$('.solonumero').on('input', function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});
```

```css
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: black;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        
 <div class="container">
      <div class="card-panel white lighten-4">
        <h4 class="header blue-text">Nueva solicitud de servicio</h4>
        <form class="col s12" name="formulario" id="addTicket" action="scripts/scriptAddTicket.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkSubmit();">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s9">
              Nombre <strong><?=$resultado['personaNombre']?> <?=$resultado['apellido']?> </strong> 
            </div>
            <div class="col s3">                 
       Tiene disponible <?=$resultado['cartera']?> Bs.F
            </div>
          </div>
  
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s6">
       Servicio a recargar:</br>
       <button type="button" class="movistar btn" name="solicitud" id="solicitud"  value="1" ></button>
       <button type="button" class="digitel btn" name="solicitud" id="solicitud"  value="2" ></button>
       <button type="button" class="directv btn" name="solicitud" id="solicitud"  value="3" ></button>
       <button type="button" class="movistartv btn" name="solicitud" id="solicitud"  value="4" ></button>
       <button type="button" class="movilnet btn" name="solicitud" id="solicitud"  value="0" disabled ></button>
     </div>
            <div class="col s6">
              Monto a recargar:</br>
              <div class="table-users">
                <table cellspacing="0" class="responsive-table">
                  <tr>
                    <td><a class="  btn  hvr-pulse"  id="300">300</a></td>
                    <td><a class="  btn  hvr-pulse"  id="400">400</a></td>
                    <td><a class="  btn  hvr-pulse"  id="500">500</a></td>
                    <td><a class="  btn  hvr-pulse"  id="600">600</a></td>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr> 
                    <td><a class=" btn  hvr-pulse"   id="700">700</a></td>
                    <td><a class=" btn  hvr-pulse"   id="800">800</a></td>
                    <td><a class=" btn  hvr-pulse"   id="900">900</a></td>
                    <td><a class=" btn  hvr-pulse"   id="1000">1000</a></td>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr>
                    <td><a class="btn  hvr-pulse"   id="1500">1500</a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn  hvr-pulse"   id="2000">2000</a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn  hvr-pulse"   id="2500">2500</a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn  hvr-pulse"   id="3000">3000</a></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <input placeholder="escriba monto sin comas o seleccione el monto de la lista" class="solonumero"  id="monto">
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
   
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" size="60" class="solonumero" >
              <label for="titulo">Número de teléfono o servicio a recargar</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <button type="reset" class="btn grey waves-effect especial hvr-pulse" >Limpiar</button>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <button id="btsubmit" type="submit" class="col s4 ud red col  btn waves-effect especial hvr-pulse">Enviar</button>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

lo que necesito hacer, o aprender a hacerlo ahora es como hacer que se al presionar un boton en la primera parte de la izquierda, se deje presionado tomando el valor de ese boton , en la segunda que deje el valor puesto por ubicado en el input y el tercero el numero para mandarlos a mi otro archivo por post donde seran guardados en mi bd

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que quieres hacer debes apuntar a `radio button`, este es un ejemplo tomando como referencia https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/7nj48

```css
ul.chec-radio {
    margin: 15px;
}
ul.chec-radio li.pz {
    display: inline;
}
.chec-radio .radio-inline .clab {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    height: 34px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="radio"]:checked+div {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="radio"]:checked+div:before {
    content: "\e013";
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<ul class="chec-radio">
 <li class="pz">
  <label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" checked="" id="movistar" name="solicitud" class="pro-chx" value="1">
   <div class="clab">Movistar</div>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li class="pz">
  <label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" id="digitel" name="solicitud" class="pro-chx" value="2" checked>
   <div class="clab">Digitel</div>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li class="pz">
  <label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" id="directv" name="solicitud" class="pro-chx" value="3">
   <div class="clab">Directv</div>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li class="pz">
  <label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" id="movistartv" name="solicitud" class="pro-chx" value="4">
   <div class="clab">MovistarTV</div>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li class="pz">
  <label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" id="movilnet" name="solicitud" class="pro-chx" value="0" disabled>
   <div class="clab">Movilnet</div>
  </label>
 </li>
</ul>
```